# How does Facebook Graph API near_by query choose the places to return?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm experimenting with searching places through Facebook Graph API. Actually, I'm searching for any place (i.e., "q=*&type=place") around a given center in a given distance.

I'm getting different results using different access_token (for different users using the same App). For example, place A shows up on results of one of the user but not on others.

Is it the expected behaviour? What's the rationale behind choosing the places to show to a user?

Answer (score 0):

The results returned from a nearby search are Facebook pages that are places. One possibility could be that some of those pages have age restrictions and you may be searching with an access token representing, say an underaged user.